# How to create a Push/slide Menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, less

I am trying to create a Push/slide out menu system on my site like how [www.squarespace.com](http://www.squarespace.com) has, however I don't know how to do so.

My site is a Squarespace site and it uses html, json and less (you can ad .js files too): [splitblog.squarespace.com/](https://splitblog.squarespace.com/)

My site.region file for navigation is:

```
<squarespace:navigation navigationId="mainNav" template="navigation" />
```

Which pulls the information from navigation.block which is this:

```
<nav id="main-navigation" class="main-navigation" data-content-field="navigation-mainNav">
  <ul>
    {.repeated section items}

        <li class="{.section active} active-link{.end}{.if folderActive} active-folder{.end}">
          {.folder?}
            <!--FOLDER-->
              <a href="{collection.fullUrl}">{collection.navigationTitle}</a>
              <ul>
                {.repeated section items}
                  <!--COLLECTION IN A FOLDER-->
                  {.collection?}
                    <li class="{.section active} active-link{.end}">
                      <a href="{collection.fullUrl}">
                        {collection.navigationTitle}
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  {.end}
                  <!--EXTERNAL LINK IN A FOLDER-->
                  {.section externalLink}
                    <li>
                      <a href="{url}"{.section newWindow} target="_blank"{.end}>
                        {title}
                      </a>
                    </li>
                  {.end}
                {.end}
              </ul>
          {.or}
            <!--COLLECTION-->
            {.section collection}
              <a href="{fullUrl}">{navigationTitle}</a>
            {.end}
            <!--EXTERNAL LINK-->
            {.section externalLink}
              <a href="{url}"{.section newWindow} target="_blank"{.end}>
                {title}
              </a>
            {.end}
          {.end}
        </li>
    {.end}
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Then the .less styling for the menu is:

```
.main-navigation {
  ul {  
    padding-left: 0;
    li {
      display: inline-block;
      ul {
        display: none;
      }
      &:not(:last-child) {
        margin-right: .5em;
      }
      &:hover > ul {
        display: inline-block;
      }
      &.active-link > a {
        color: salmon;
      }
      &.active-folder > a {
        color: orange;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated.  Feel free to offer css and js solutions.  Thanks!

### Edit

Here is an example of what I want to impliment:  [codepen](http://codepen.io/jetpacmonkey/pen/ktIJz)

Comment: I have used pushy in the past and it works nicely: https://github.com/christophery/pushy.  At the least it will give you an idea of how to tackle the problem.

Comment: can u provide a jsfiddle .. will be easy to help you

Comment: Here is an example of what I want to impliment:  http://codepen.io/jetpacmonkey/pen/ktIJz

Comment: so you want a panel that is scrollable and one which is not scrollabe?

Comment: I want to add this to the right side of my template.  I want the hamburger icon to be in the top right. I want it to be the same as squarespace.com's menu system.  Yes I would like the menu to be scrollable if there are a lot of items in the menu.

Comment: You can check this: http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/sp3ju/3/. Change around the code to slide from the right?

Answer (score 0):

Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ucw63/1/).

This should give you an idea about how the requirement can be achieved.

```
$(document).on("click","#button", function(){

    $('#div2').animate({ width:"20%" }, 200);
    $('#div1').animate({width:"80%" }, 200);

});

$(document).on("click","#close", function(){

    $('#div2').animate({visibility:"hidden" , width:"0%" }, 200); 
    $('#div1').animate({width:"100%" }, 200);

});


#div1
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    position:fixed;
}
#div2
{
    height:100%;
    width:0%;
    float:right;

}

#button
{
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-right:20px;
    float:right;
}
```

Comment: Not what I'm trying to do.  Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I'm trying to create the same menu/navigation system as www.squarespace.com  - Where you click on the menu icon, and the menu slides out from the right.

Comment: updated the fiddle .. replace the dummy data with the requirement elements

Comment: Hmm... I tried implementing the code, however it looks like the js isn't activating the menu.. Would you mind taking a look? https://splitblog.squarespace.com/

Answer (score 0):

This might give you an idea of how to achieve this.

http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/off-canvas-menu-animated-links

Also foundation has a offcanvas menu in their framework that you can look at and see how they created this.

http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/offcanvas.html